# Do C# NPOI support phonetic text (japanese/chinese text)?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I am converting excel file .xlsx with phonetic text (Japanese text) but the output file gives out warning that there are unreadable contents, and the data are missing from the file.

It seems that the issues were because NPOI can't process the phonetic guide from Microsoft Excel in Japanese language.

This only applies on .xlsx files and not .xls files.

[image: Excel file]

I'm not sure how to attach the sample excel file but the image above shows what it looks like. Basically, if you use Microsoft Excel in Japanese version, there will be automatic phonetic guide for every kanji (Chinese character).

```
public void writeoutput(string val)
{
    try
    {
        IWorkbook book;
        string outPath = "<path for input file>";

        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(outPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            try
            {
                book = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                book = null;
            }

            if (book == null)
            {
                book = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            }

            file.Close();
        }

        //ISheet sheet = outputSheet.GetSheet("Sheet1");
        ISheet sheet = book.GetSheetAt(0);

        sheet.CopySheet("NewSheet", false);

        IRow dataRow = sheet.GetRow(35) ?? sheet.CreateRow(35);
        ICell cell = dataRow.GetCell(8) ?? dataRow.CreateCell(8);

        cell.SetCellValue(val);

        //File.Delete(outPath);
        outPath = "<path for output file>";

        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(outPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            book.Write(file);
            file.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        textBox2.Text = "done";
    }
}
```

I tried disable the phonetic guide in Microsoft Excel and the processing of the .xlsx file works with no issues but I can only disable the phonetic guide on the text one by one and it is very time consuming.

Comment: please provide sample xlsx file, otherwise, no way to check it.

Comment: I am not sure how to attach xlsx file so I attached an image instead. Hope it's enough.